# How to get double values in athena stored to be shown as Integers

Tags: amazon-athena

Currently we have a database column of type double and all the values are stored in exponential format

`0055828993167` is stored as `5.5828993167E10` 
while fetching the values we always require to convert back to long value `new BigDecimal(5.5828993167E10).longValueExact()`

> As this has to done in almost all places and we cannot change the
>   column type,
>   can we some how cast the double -> long in athena while
>   querying the results ?

[documentation](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/conversion.html) is very little :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the equivalent of long values do `CAST(the_column AS BIGINT)`

Comment: Can this be done in the table definition itself? Or only when querying?

Comment: Using an integer type for integers should do the trick. The conversion is necessary because the table says the numbers are doubles, when in fact they are integers.